# Giving at least 28 days notice at a designated register office

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand the meaning of "giving at least 28 days notice at a designated register office" in the following paragraph:

> Laws regarding marriage of a foreign-national require that if one member of the couple is from outside the European Union or Switzerland, both must appear in person to give at least 28 days notice at a designated register office.  Part of the notice includes evidence of the marriage visa.

Does it mean that the couple will have to stay in the U.K. for 28 days before they can register as Civil Partners? And shouldn't it be "28 day notice" instead of "28 days notice"?

Here is the [source](https://uk.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/local-resources-of-u-s-citizens/marriage-and-civil-partnerships/)

Comment: This is from a website owned by the US gov. The topic is "U.S. citizens coming to the United Kingdom to marry U.K. citizens or persons settled here." US immigration and citizenship laws for aliens are notoriously complex. Hire a professional legal advisor to tell you what the law means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you give [notice](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/notice?q=give%20notice), it means that you are giving "information or a warning given about something that is going to happen in the future"- in this case, notice that you intend to get married.

This paragraph states that the couple must to go to a register office at least 28 days before they intend to marry, and that they must show (amongst other things) a marriage visa. It does **not** state that the couple must stay in the UK between giving notice and the actual marriage.

---

Regarding the plural: in this paragraph, 28 is used to specify a number of days, and the number is more than 1, so **days** should definitely have an **s**. Furthermore, we generally use a [possessive 's](https://www.theenglishspace.com/grammar/possessives/possessive-time-phrases.html) with a period of time:

> My boss gave me a month's notice [to leave work]
>
> I can't just drop everything and fly to the US at a day's notice

In the paragraph that you quoted, there are 28 days, so the apostrophe should be written after the s: **days'**. Most people use the apostrophe for a day, a week or a month, but  it is [often omitted when there are several days](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=28%20days%20notice%2C28%20days%20%27%20notice&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C28%20days%20notice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C28%20days%20%27%20notice%3B%2Cc0), as in this case.

Note that it would not be necessary to put an s if 28-day is used adjectivally rather than 28 being used as a number. Generally a determiner (**the** or **a**) would precede the adjective:

> He's just got back from **a** 3-week holiday in Greece
>   **The** 2-day strike has caused severe disruption.

For notice, you might say something like

> The wedding will take place after **a** 28-day notice period.

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thank you all for your detailed explanations  !